# Compare nonnormal trends

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, trend

I have two groups of nonnormal time-series data. I want to compare the difference in trends between them statistically. So, I've calculated the Theil-Sen slop for each group and want to compare the two slopes for statistical significance. Is it correct to use Sen slopes for them? How to compare the two slopes? Thank you.